# Discuss the continuity of the following function F(x)

Tags: real-analysis

The function $F(x)$ is defined as 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases} x &\text{ if $x$ is rational} \\ -x &\text{ if $x$ is irrational.}\end{cases}$$

I think it should be that is discontinuous everywhere but it is not right according to the answer key.

Comment: It's continuous at $0$.

Comment: Hmm it is right can I give some explanation pls it would be helpful.

Comment: Oops   can  U give some explanation

Comment: Obviously $F(0) = 0$. And $\forall\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta >0$ such that $|x|<\delta\implies |F(x) - F(0)|\lt\epsilon$. One can choose $\delta = \epsilon /2$ for example. This proves that $\lim_{x\to 0}F(x) = 0=F(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is continuous at $0$ because of the sequential criterion.

If you take a sequence $(x_n)$ such that

$$x_n\to 0.$$

Then you can extract two sub-sequences:

- $(y_k)$ the sequence of rationals within $(x_n)$
- $(y_k)$ the sequence of irrationals within $(x_n)$.

*Remark: $(y_k)$ and $(x_k)$ may be finite sequences, then you can conclude simply from here. I will assume in the following that they are not finite.*

Then

$$F(y_k)=y_k\to 0$$

and

$$F(z_k)=-z_k\to 0.$$

So

$$F(x_n)\to 0$$

and finally $F$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Then you can show that $F$ is discontinuous at $x$ if $x\ne 0$.